# How to bind all submodel from Part view and partial view in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have one ViewModel which contains some submodel for each feature.
Below is just an example

```
public class CollegeModel
{
    public CollegeModel()
    {
        Teachers = new Teachers();
        Students = new Students();
        Workers = new Workers();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Teachers Teachers { get; set; }
    public Students Students { get; set; }
    public Workers Workers { get; set; }
}

public class Teachers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Students
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age{ get; set; }
}

public class Workers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

This is the parent view

```
@model OneClickShowApp.ViewModel.CollegeModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveExportData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div>
    @if (Model.Students != null)
    {
        Html.Partial("StudentDetails", Model.Students)
    }
    @if (Model.Teachers != null)
    {
        Html.Partial("TeachersDetails", Model.Teachers)
    }
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 offset-8 text-center">
    <input type="submit" value="Export"/>
</div>

}
```

Now I want to show `CollegeModel` in a view, where I will have to load each entity as a new partial view.

I will provide a submit button on the parent view, where I need to send all the details to some action class, I am not able to do that.

When I am sending all details, I am not getting `PartialModel` data in server side

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Do you want to bind model data to partial views? Can you provide part of your controller code?

Comment: @Chaodeng, Controller will form "CollegeModel" object, which will have 3 properties:
Teachers 
Students
Workers 

I want to create 3 Partial View, for each properties, and need to make sure on click of submit button which is present in Parent View, all data from all partial view should be sent to Controller